# childViewControllers is empty after calling addChildViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I have a question regarding add/remove childviewcontrollers with ContainerView.

I have a UIViewController named "ContainerViewController" that contains a ContainerView, and this ContainerView has a UIViewController named "ContainerLinkViewController". I also have four other UIViewControllers that will be added to or removed from this "ContainerLinkViewController" whenever user a clicks one of the tab button that is placed at the bottom of "ContainerViewController". The storyboard looks like below.

[image]

NOTE that the custom segues connected to those four UiViewcontrollers are just empty segue that does nothing but show visual connection in storyboard.

So what I do is first add the First Tab ViewController to "ContainerLinkViewController" as a childViewController by using below code in viewDidLoad().

```
let firstTabViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FirstTabViewController") as! FirstTabViewController
self.addChildViewController(firstTabViewController)
firstTabViewController.view.frame = self.view.bounds
self.view.addSubview(firstTabViewController.view)
firstTabViewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
```

After this initial setup, whenever user tabs on one of those tab buttons, I send signal from "ContainerViewController" that which UIViewController is to be added as new childViewController to "ContainerLinkViewController" and switching the old childViewController and this new childViewController using the below code.

```
func swapViewControllers(from : UIViewController, to : UIViewController) {
    from.willMove(toParentViewController: nil)
    self.addChildViewController(to)
    to.view.frame = self.view.bounds

    self.transition(from: from, to: to, duration: 1.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.transitionCrossDissolve, animations: nil) {
        finished in
        from.view.removeFromSuperview()
        from.removeFromParentViewController()
        to.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
    }
}
```

Before calling this "swaptViewControllers()", I take the old childViewController by doing the following.

```
let oldChildViewController = self.childViewControllers.last
```

My problem is that this "oldChildViewController" is nil when I click one of those tabs for the first time right after the initial setup. So the function "swaptViewControllers()" does not even called because the self.childViewControllers is empty.

I have been struggling with this for few days now and could not find clear answer to solve this. So I decided to ask here to get some help about what might cause this.

Any help?? Thanks.

NOTE : I am using swift 3. Maybe this would help to answer my question since it seems lots of things changed fro swift 2.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you using a container view controller to achieve the same functionality that a tab bar controller provides for free?

Comment: @Aaron because as far as I know, the default tabbar cannot be fully customized and I need to be able to customize it for my project. ^.^